# newtype-like operational semantics for a GADT where the type fully determines the constructor

Tags: haskell, gadt, coercion, newtype

Suppose I have a GADT like the following:

```
data Tag = A | B | C

data Payload (tag :: Tag) where
  PA :: Int -> Payload A
  PB :: Double -> Payload B
  PC :: Bool -> Payload C
```

I want `Payload` to have no runtime representation on its own -- i.e. I want to have `Coercible Int (Payload A)`, I want zero-cost pattern matching, and in general I want it to behave as if I had the following three newtype definitions instead:

```
newtype PayloadA = PA Int
newtype PayloadB = PB Double
newtype PayloadC = PC Bool
```

Is there a way to convince GHC to give me that?

Comment: Also, I think you *shouldn't* get zero-cost pattern matching, formally speaking. The `Payload` GADT still contains information (i.e. if the type parameter was existential, matching would give you an equality proof)

Comment: @oisdk: But surely those type equality proofs are irrelevant at runtime?

Comment: For the first one, you can have "given" and "required" constraints for a pattern synonym. The way it works is very weird, so I don't really know the precise details.

For the second question, I mean basically if you had a function `fn :: Payload tag -> f tag -> ()`, by pattern matching on the first arg you would reveal the type of the second. You're then allowed to work as if the type of `tag` is whatever type you discovered. I *think* that removing the tag (and therefor the need for a pattern match) would break type safety. It's why you can't do irrefutable pattern-matches on GADTs.

Comment: I'm somewhat familiar with pattern synonyms, but I am not seeing what the type of the scrutinee would be if there is no GADT at all, just the three newtypes.

Comment: Ok, I actually see what you mean now. Pattern synonyms don't actually let you avoid lugging a tag around. In which case, I can't think of a solution!

Answer (score 7):

This looks impossible to achieve, at least with current GHC. Assume your `Payload A` had the same representation of `Int`, and so on.

```
data Tag = A | B | C

data Payload (tag :: Tag) where
  PA :: Int -> Payload A
  PB :: Double -> Payload B
  PC :: Bool -> Payload C
```

Then, how should we implement this?

```
foo :: Payload tag -> Int
foo (PA i) = i
foo (PB _) = 1
foo (PC _) = 2
```

To implement `foo`, we somehow need to extract the `tag` from the `Payload tag`, but that is impossible if `Payload tag` does not store the tag in its representation.

What we could do, instead, is to separate the runtime tag representation from its payload data.

```
type family Payload (tag :: Tag) where
   Payload 'A = Int
   Payload 'B = Double
   Payload 'C = Bool
```

Now, `Payload 'A` is exactly an `Int`. We however lose the ability to write `foo`, since the tag is no longer stored at runtime along the payload. We can instead write this:

```
-- singleton, could be auto-generated using the singletons library
data STag (tag :: Tag) where
    SA :: STag 'A
    SB :: STag 'B
    SC :: STag 'C

bar :: STag tag -> Payload tag -> Int
bar PA i = i
bar PB _ = 1
bar PC _ = 2
```

Note how we essentially add the tag as an argument, since we do need it to be represented at runtime.

Comment: Hmm. What if we had an extra `KnownTag` constraint on the type of `bar`, with the appropriate singleton factory function in there? In that case, I expect the `KnownTag` dictionary would not be passed around at runtime, instead it would mostly be optimized away via specialization?

Comment: @Cactus It's possible. Even without the constraint `bar PA` could similarly be optimized by inlining. There should not be much difference between the constraint-based and the argument-based versions: both can be optimized in similar ways, I guess. Hence, we can choose the most convenient one.

Comment: Wouldn't that type family be a better match to what was initially desired as a data family with newtype instances?

Comment: @Carl Better match than what? I think it's the only available option with current GHC.

Comment: I guess you can't have closed data families... But my goal was to have instances actually be different types, not just synonyms.

Comment: @Carl Can't you use `newtype P tag = P (Payload tag)`, where `Payload` is a closed type family? You can then write instances on `P 'A`, etc.

Comment: If you use a constraint instead of extra parameter, there would be nowhere to infer `tag` from, since type family is non-injective. You'd have to pass in the `tag` via visible type application.

Answer (score 5):

You can do like:

```
data family Payload (tag :: Tag)
newtype instance Payload A = PA Int
newtype instance Payload B = PB Double
newtype instance Payload C = PC Bool
```

This meets your requirement of actually having types distinct from `Int`, `Double`, `Bool`, and of having the operation semantics of a newtype. Of course, the price you pay is you won't be able to pattern-match to determine which is which. But you can recover such things with a typeclass or by explicitly passing the tag (which mostly amount to the same thing under the hood); for example:

```
class Foo (t :: Tag) where foo :: Payload t -> Int
instance Foo A where foo (PA i) = i
instance Foo B where foo (PB _) = 2
instance Foo C where foo (PC _) = 3
```